Application shutdown with windev mobile 25
Description of the error when my application shutdown
I'm using windev mobile 25
The application works on some smartphones and shutdown on others.i don't Know why.i suspect android version but i'm not sure.
I looked for the problem on the link above without solution.please i need your help.thanks in advance
